# PHP-activerecord - 'Class \ActivityQuestion does not exist'

Tags: codeigniter-2

I have tables
- topics(id, name)
- activities(id, name)
- activities_questions(id, activity_id)

I have 2 models named

- Activity.php

class Activity extends ActiveRecord\Model {

```
static $belongs_to = array(array('topic'));
static $has_many = array(array('activity_question'));
```

}

-Activities_question.php

class ActivitiesQuestion extends ActiveRecord\Model {

```
static $table_name = 'activities_questions';

static $belongs_to = array(
    array('activity')
);
```

}

Am I doing something wrong or I am missing something in my model name or file name. I am getting errors something like

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class \ActivityQuestion does not exist'

I need help, I am not sure about the correcting.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh i found out my mistake. My model name and model file are not same.